# Is there a way to download knowledge articles as PDF(Salesforce)?

Tags: pdf, salesforce, salesforce-communities

We have a requirement from a client to download knowledge articles as PDF. Is there any way to do so?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.